# What design button is web2py book referring to?

Tags: web2py

The [web2py book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/3) says

> "To edit an application, click on the design button for the newly
>   created application."

but I dont see any such button and the docs dont have a screenshot of what they are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That instruction is out of date -- the button is now labeled "edit" (when you click and go to the "edit" page, you'll notice in the URL that the name of the function used to generate the page is "design", but the page itself and the button are now labeled with "edit").

Answer (score 0):

Before you can see the Edit button, you need to log in to the Administrative interface.